# XP Pro laptop cannot access files on domain server

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp

I'm managing about 20 computer for a small business, and set up their network yesterday. We have a server that fills multiple roles, including DHCP, Domain Admin, and file sharing/storage.

Today all of the computers have access to the internet and the server files with the exception of one. This happens to be a laptop and not a workstation, but it's still using hard wired internet(although I've also tested with wireless). The issue we're having is that this one computer cannot log in to the domain. At bootup, he logs in to the laptop with his credentials and logs in to the domain(called Radar). No problems here.

This is an engineering company that uses WinXP so the laptop is old and slow. It usually tries to sync files on the domain but the progress bar never moves. Sometimes a domain login window pops up, and if I enter his credentials and hit enter, nothing happens. The login window acts like nothing happened; it's movable, credentials can be changed, and it can be closed with no problem. It just never actually connects.

Now if I close the sync window and try to access the domain server files I get similar, but sometimes stranger issues. Sometimes it says that the domain is unavailable. Sometimes it says he does not have access to the files. Sometimes a window will pop up saying a possible security threat was detected. If we do get a login window to pop up, it's the same deal as before. He is one of 2 users with Administrator privileges, the other of which has no problem logging in and accessing the server.

He does get internet access with no issues, and I've checked the ipconfig to make sure it's an IP assigned by the DHCP with the correct gateway. No problems there, he just can't access the files. I'm not much of an IT person, so can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Edit> I forgot another very common behavior, where clicking on a drive on the file server will show him the file tree but if you look through the folders all of them are empty. Could this be an issue with the drive mapping?

Edit 2> Here is a log I pulled from his machine after a login attempt:

> Event Type:         Error
>
> Event Source:     NETLOGON
>
> Event Category: None
>
> Event ID:              5719
>
> Date:                    8/2/2012
>
> Time:                    11:02:40 AM
>
> User:                    N/A
>
> Computer:           C046
>
> Description:
>   No Domain Controller is available for domain RADAR due to the following:
>
> There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request. .
>
> Make sure that the computer is connected to the network and try again. If the problem >persists, please contact your domain administrator.
>
> Data:
>
> 0000: 5e 00 00 c0               ^..À

There was also an error log about not being able to find a domain controller to set the time, so it's not making a connection with the DC. There are no relevant logs on the server side of things.

Comment: `"including DHCP, **Domain Admin**, and file sharing/storage."` Do you mean Domain Controller?

Comment: What does `"he just can't access the files."` mean? Do you get an error? What does it say? What's the event log say? Who is the logged in user and what are that use's effective permissions on the share's NTFS ACLs?

Comment: Can he get to any other network resources?  Is that just that one server he can't get to?

Comment: Oops, yes. The server is the Domain Controller.

By can't access the files I mean he gets the errors I described, and it could be one of many. However the most common is that a window to login to the domain pops up and it doesn't do anything.

I will check to see if he can log in to someone elses computer once they're done with a meeting.

Comment: @Alex is that laptop joined to the domain and is the user logged in with an account that should have access to the sahre?

Comment: @Alex you really need to check the `Event Logs` on both the the client and the Domain Controller.  If the computer can communicate with the DC, the DC logs should say why his request is rejected.  If the computer can't communicate with the DC, the client `Event Logs` should give you a clue as to why.  Until you provide that information, any answer will be little more than blind guesswork.

Comment: MDMarra, yes the laptop is registered in the active directory and is using an account with multiple privileges also registered in the active directory.

Comment: @HoplessN00b, I'm looking through Event Viewer on the server now, would I be looking for failed security audits?

Comment: @Alex Yes. Would be easiest for that category to prompt a failed connection attempt from the client to see if it generates a security failure, so you don't have to filter through random bad password requests and such.  You'd also want to look for any errors or warnings related to the long list of things that could cause a failure to connect to or authenticate against a domain controller.

Comment: @HoplessN00b, thanks very much for the lead. I'll look into these on both computers and see if I find anything interesting.

Answer (score 2):

According to that error, the client computer can't locate a Domain Controller. This is almost always a DNS issue. All domain clients should be configured to use a DNS server that holds the zones for the Active Directory that it is joined to. In almost all cases, this means the Domain Controllers for the domain.

No internal clients should have anything configured in their DNS Server list other than DCs that also have the DNS role installed.

---

To troubleshoot this, run `nslookup <your domain>` and `nslookup <your domain controller(s)>`. If you don't get the correct response back, then the client DNS configuration is your problem.

Comment: I have the DNS property set to the IP of the Domain Controller(it's also the DNS and DHCP) and 8.8.8.8 is gone, but nslookup still says:


>Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
>Address:  8.8.8.8

>*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find radar: Non-existent >domain


I tried rebooting the server and cycled all the networking equipment, is there a command to force an update or something?

Comment: If that's what you're getting, then you didn't change it correctly. What does `ipconfig /all` on the client tell you that the configured DNS servers are?

Answer (score 0):

check the network settings to see if he has a DNS server specified. even if the computer is set to use DHCP to get an IP address, it can still be set up to use different DNS servers.

Comment: Which DNS should he be using? If I remember correctly, he had 8.8.8.8 and the address of the Domain Controller as DNS servers in ipconfig.

Comment: so your dhcp server is handing out googles dns servers? or is that hardcoded overriding  the dhcp settings.

Comment: I put it into the DHCP settings yesterday during troubleshooting.

Comment: take it out. on a domain network, the first DNS server in the list should be an Active Directory enabled DNS server. in many networks, the DNS server runs on the domain controller.

Comment: @longneck `"on a domain network, the first DNS server in the list should be an Active Directory enabled DNS server"` - That should say "on a domain network, **all** DNS servers should be Active Directory enabled DCs"

Comment: Thanks, it's out now but still no change.